# Change one element of ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to change one item (ImageView) in a specific row of a ListView. Now I tried it to change it through the `onItemClickListener` provided View to change it. It also works !

But somehow when I scroll up and down other listview rows getting also changed. I found something about the problem `"view recycling"` but I really didnt find a solution for it.

Someone can help ?

**EDIT**:
Some code here :

My Listener :

```
LV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ...
        updateEQAnimation(position,view);
        ...
        }
```

The function which should change it

```
private void updateEQAnimation(int index, View view){

   ColorStateList sColorStatePlaying;
   ColorStateList sColorStateNotPlaying;

   sColorStatePlaying = ColorStateList.valueOf(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    if(view == null)
        return;
    AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.anim_current_song);
    ImageView EQ_ANIM = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_eq_animation);
    EQ_ANIM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    EQ_ANIM.setImageDrawable(animation);
    EQ_ANIM.setImageTintList(sColorStatePlaying);
    animation.start();}
```

getView method :

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rview = view;
    holder = null;

    if (rview == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_song, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder(rview);
        rview.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rview.getTag();
    }

    mArtLoader.loadBitmap(AL_songlist.get(position).getAlbumArtPath(), holder.imgAlbumart);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(AL_songlist.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.txtArtist.setText(AL_songlist.get(position).getArtist());

    if(Main.songService.svc_mpcontroller != null && Main.global_music_controller != null) {
        if (AL_songlist.get(position).getID() == Main.global_music_controller.get_current_id()) {
            ColorStateList sColorStatePlaying;
            ColorStateList sColorStateNotPlaying;

            sColorStatePlaying = ColorStateList.valueOf(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.anim_current_song);
            holder.imgEQAnimation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imgEQAnimation.setImageDrawable(animation);
            holder.imgEQAnimation.setImageTintList(sColorStatePlaying);
            animation.start();
        }
    }

    return rview;
}
```

Comment: You should use getItemId() for the item you want to change, then work on that id on further actions.

Comment: I edited and posted my code currently

Comment: Onur kardes. getItemId hep ayni int geri veriyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will explain view recycling then I will get to your issue. Say you can see 8 list items on the screen at one time. When you scroll the list down and item number 1 goes off screen and item number 10 comes on screen, item number 10 will reuse item number 1s view. This means that item number 10 will look exactly like item number 1 unless you update it accordingly in your adapters `getView` method.

Now that we understand View recycling you can see why other items will have your new drawable even though you didn't click them. You will have to store in your dataset that you use for your adapter which items have that image, whether it be an ArrayList in the Adapter or it be a custom object that the Adapter uses. Then in the `getView` of your adapter you could do the following:

```
if(hasImage)
{
    ColorStateList sColorStatePlaying;
    ColorStateList sColorStateNotPlaying;

    sColorStatePlaying = ColorStateList.valueOf(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.anim_current_song);
    ImageView EQ_ANIM = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_eq_animation);
    EQ_ANIM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    EQ_ANIM.setImageDrawable(animation);
    EQ_ANIM.setImageTintList(sColorStatePlaying);
    animation.start();
}
else
{
    // Set the default image
}
```

Edit:
You should add an else statement in your `getView`

```
    if(Main.songService.svc_mpcontroller != null && Main.global_music_controller != null) {
        if (AL_songlist.get(position).getID() == Main.global_music_controller.get_current_id()) {
            ColorStateList sColorStatePlaying;
            ColorStateList sColorStateNotPlaying;

            sColorStatePlaying = ColorStateList.valueOf(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.anim_current_song);
            holder.imgEQAnimation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imgEQAnimation.setImageDrawable(animation);
            holder.imgEQAnimation.setImageTintList(sColorStatePlaying);
            animation.start();
        }
    }
    else
        holder.imgEQAnimation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: hmmm... Ok I will try it. So if I understand it right I could make a list where for example I put boolean values (default = all false). And the one Ive clicked I have to make true. And then I have to check it everytime in getView if list.get(position) is true or not ? Did I understand it right ?

Comment: Yep thats how it works. What is your adapters dataset currently? If you were to call list.get(position), what would it return?

Comment: I still got the same problem. My dataset is a custom object array where one of them have an boolean value which shows that the Image has to be changed

Comment: Could you add the `getView` code from your adapter to the question and I'll have a look.

Comment: I did. Im really thankfull to you that you take your time to help me.Somehow this is still making these dublicates

Comment: I've modified my answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thats really funny mate. I did it and it worked and then I watched out for a new comment by you and now I see you wrote the same solution :D Thanks for everything !

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)